# How to check if a power series formula is correct?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, power-series

Given the next power series convergent within the interval $(-3,-1)$:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac{2^{2n+1}(x+2)^{2n}}{7^{2n}}$$

I need to express it as a formula, so using the Geometric series:

- First I reestructure the series to make it similar to the geometric series

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}2^{2n+1}}{7^{2n}}(x+2)^{2n}$

$(-2)\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}2^{2n}}{7^{2n}}(x+2)^{2n}$

$(-2)\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n}\biggl(\frac{2^2}{7^2}(x+2)^2\biggr)^n$

$(-2)\sum_{n=0}^\infty \biggl((-1)\frac{2^2}{7^2}(x+2)^2\biggr)^n$

- According to the geometric series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n = \frac{1}{1-z}$ so $z=-\frac{4}{49}(x+2)^2$

That leaves us with:

$$S(x)=\frac{-2}{1+\frac{4}{49}(x+2)^2} $$

Now my question is: How do I check this formula is correct?

Comment: Check some values by hand?  Taking $x=-2$ your formula gives $\frac {-2}1=-2$ while the only non-zero term in the sum is $(-1)^{0+1}\times \frac {2^1}{7^0}=-2$.    You could also try $x=-1$, and so on.

Comment: Another good check is to work backwards.  Let $z=\frac 27\times (x+2)$, and write out the familiar expansion of $\frac 1{1+z^2}$.  Should be easy to check that this gets you back to your original series.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think that your query showed good work, was nicely formatted, and had no mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @RobertTheTutor pointed in the answer above, a rigorous way to prove it will be to compute the derivatives of both functions and compare them (that is, by checking if both have the same Taylor polynomial). But if you are looking for a non-rigorous way of doing it, I would recommend you to try these options:

- Check the [series representation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-2%2F%281%2B%284%2F49%29*%28%28x%2B2%29**2%29%29) section in the WolframAlpha site.
- Check by hand the first values of their derivatives at a certain $x\in(-3,-1)$.
- Code a simple script where you calculate an approximated value of the original series $$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{100}\cdots$$ and compare it with the expected value of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to calculate derivatives of your power series and your solution and see that they match.  Another is to evaluate both at specific values of x.